# How to find the threshold value of an image in Java?

Tags: java

This is my first post so excuse me if I miss something out. Basically I am provided with code to make a normal image into Grayscale and then I need to convert the Grayscale image into Thresholded image, but before I do that I need to figure out the value of the Threshold itself and I can't seem to figure out how to do so.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class GrayScale {
BufferedImage image;
int width;
int height;

public GrayScale() {
    try {
        File input = new File("mysteryBird.jpg");
        image = ImageIO.read(input);
        width = image.getWidth();
        height = image.getHeight();
        int[] hist = new int[256];
        for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
                Color c = new Color(image.getRGB(j, i));
                int red = (int) (c.getRed() * 0.299);
                int green = (int) (c.getGreen() * 0.587);
                int blue = (int) (c.getBlue() * 0.114);
                Color newColor = new Color(red + green + blue, red + green + blue, red + green + blue);
                image.setRGB(j, i, newColor.getRGB());
            }
        }
        File ouptut = new File("grayscale.jpg");
        ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", ouptut);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi John, what have you tried so far? Which libraries would you like to use?

Comment: @hakamairi I can only use the ones I have so far. They hint that I should use an array. Initialize the array to all zeroes and read each pixel of the grayscale image. Then if I get a pixel value of x I should add 1 to array[x]